# Why did Randall give the Joker the gun?

Tags: plot-explanation, joker

In *Joker* (2019), why did Randall give the Joker the gun? What was his actual motive? Did he give the gun thinking that when Joker will be performing he will drop it - as it happened?

Or did he really care for the Joker as he said?

Comment: see https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/104978/why-did-randall-say-that-arthur-joker-tried-to-buy-a-gun-from-him

Comment: Did he, though?